# what is the best way to call a group of results from mySQL by quarter?

Tags: php, mysql, date

I am looking to order a set of results of a mySQL data by quarter. They have data fields, so I am wondering if I should be doing this in PHP or in the query itself?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

if you have date field in the db use it  to group with it,

[like](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_quarter):

```
group by QUARTER(date)
```

of course if you want to take in account the years also

[use](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_year)

```
group by YEAR(date) , QUARTER(date)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use GROUP BY Clause in mysql query and return results as -

```
group by Quarter(date)
```

Where Quarter is a pre-defined function in mysql.

Answer (score 0):

I would do it in the DB - look up the MySQL function Quarter(Date).